# How to check a MutableList's element or a String input is a number?

Tags: string, function, kotlin, mutablelist

I run into a problem in the code below.

```
fun main() {
val table = mutableListOf(
    mutableListOf(' ', ' ', ' '),
    mutableListOf(' ', ' ', ' '),
    mutableListOf(' ', ' ', ' ')
)

println("---------")
println("| " + table[0][0] + " " + table[0][1] + " " + table[0][2] + " |")
println("| " + table[1][0] + " " + table[1][1] + " " + table[1][2] + " |")
println("| " + table[2][0] + " " + table[2][1] + " " + table[2][2] + " |")
println("---------")

print("Enter the coordinates: ")
var coordinates = readLine()!!.split(" ").toMutableList()
var x = coordinates[0].toInt()
var y = coordinates[1].toInt()


while (x > 3 || x < 1 || y > 3 || y < 1) {
    println("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!")
    print("Enter the coordinates: ")
    coordinates = readLine()!!.split(" ").toMutableList()
    x = coordinates[0].toInt()
    y = coordinates[1].toInt()
}

while (table[x-1][y-1] == 'X' || table[x-1][y-1] == 'O') {
    println("This cell is occupied! Choose another one!")
    print("Enter the coordinates: ")
    coordinates = readLine()!!.split(" ").toMutableList()
    x = coordinates[0].toInt()
    y = coordinates[1].toInt()
}

table[x-1][y-1] = 'X'

println("---------")
println("| " + table[0][0] + " " + table[0][1] + " " + table[0][2] + " |")
println("| " + table[1][0] + " " + table[1][1] + " " + table[1][2] + " |")
println("| " + table[2][0] + " " + table[2][1] + " " + table[2][2] + " |")
println("---------")


if (table[0][0] == 'X' && table[0][1] == 'X' && table[0][2] == 'X' ||
    table[1][0] == 'X' && table[1][1] == 'X' && table[1][2] == 'X' ||
    table[2][0] == 'X' && table[2][1] == 'X' && table[2][2] == 'X' ||
    table[0][0] == 'X' && table[1][0] == 'X' && table[2][0] == 'X' ||
    table[0][1] == 'X' && table[1][1] == 'X' && table[2][1] == 'X' ||
    table[0][2] == 'X' && table[1][2] == 'X' && table[2][2] == 'X' ||
    table[0][0] == 'X' && table[1][1] == 'X' && table[2][2] == 'X' ||
    table[2][0] == 'X' && table[1][1] == 'X' && table[0][2] == 'X'
) {
    println("X wins")
} else if (table[0][0] == 'O' && table[0][1] == 'O' && table[0][2] == 'O' ||
    table[1][0] == 'O' && table[1][1] == 'O' && table[1][2] == 'O' ||
    table[2][0] == 'O' && table[2][1] == 'O' && table[2][2] == 'O' ||
    table[0][0] == 'O' && table[1][0] == 'O' && table[2][0] == 'O' ||
    table[0][1] == 'O' && table[1][1] == 'O' && table[2][1] == 'O' ||
    table[0][2] == 'O' && table[1][2] == 'O' && table[2][2] == 'O' ||
    table[0][0] == 'O' && table[1][1] == 'O' && table[2][2] == 'O' ||
    table[2][0] == 'O' && table[1][1] == 'O' && table[0][2] == 'O'
) {
    println("O wins")
}
```

}

I can check the input is not smaller or higher then 3 (coordinates) and also able to check the field is not occupied. But how can I check the input is not a string with a while loop like checking field occupation and coordinate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Table is char[][] - right? Something like `char* pC = &Table[0][0]; for(int i = 0; i<9; i++){if(*pC = /*check for the ascii code - here you can define a range*/)throw new std::exception();}else{pC++;}` Sorry, I'm a little bit out of native C Code, but should look something like that. You can do it different, but please - use foreach-loops if you think in matrices - no do-while.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mentioned, the code is in Kotlin. I understand some of your code, but it is in C. I see that yor for loop iterates through the table elements. But what I need is check the input is string or number, if it's not a number, then it need to ask for a valid number input then update the table with X or O. This part of the code is not written now.

Comment: Feels like this could really use some tips on writing better code, you could try posting this (with the answer below implemented) to codereview.stackexchange.com, because it's a bit too much to point out here in the comments. But at the very least I'd advise to give fields 3 states with an enum { X,0,EMPTY } instead of working with raw strings, and don't use mutableLists unless you have to, so not with the split()

Comment: Okay, I made a mistake, but humans can make mistakes. I'm not perfect in english because it isn't my mother language. But honestly, you can see the difference between C and Kotlin! I appreciate your advice! But I need to solve the problem in this way. I think nobody is dumb to use a string input if it is known to use a digit. But not I'm who write this task. I have to solve it in the written way. Check if the input is not a string, check if it's in out of range and check if the field is occupied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to do it like this

```
x = coordinates[0].toIntOrNull() ?: 99
y = coordinates[1].toIntOrNull() ?: 99
```

the difference with `toInt()` and `toIntOrNull()` is that `toIntOrNull()` doesn't throw an exception when it can't turn it into an Int but will return null instead. This can be redirected to a fallback number using the elvis operator `?:`. Here you can put anything that is not in your required range of 1-3. I just chose 99 to demonstrate this.

Comment: This is the easiest 'plug-and-play' solution indeed, but refactoring so the null directly retries instead of using a magic number for this would be cleaner

Comment: @somethingsomething true. and I agree with your comment under the question that there's room for much more improvement. But I thought it would be out of scope for this question. I usually refrain from suggesting answers that require major refactoring and therefore gave a solution that would do the job with as little changes as possible

Answer (score 1):

I've done it this way:

```
print("Enter the coordinates: ")
var coordinates = readLine()!!.split(" ").toMutableList()


while (coordinates[0].length > 1 || coordinates[1].length > 1 || coordinates[0].length > 1 && coordinates[1].length > 1 ) {
    println("You should enter numbers!")
    print("Enter the coordinates: ")
    coordinates = readLine()!!.split(" ").toMutableList()
}
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this approach over @Ivoks previous answer?

Comment: Just want to find another solution.

Comment: It doesn't look like this will work for single letters